# Which passive regeneration is the most effective?

Tags: guild-wars-2

There are several skills or traits which apply health regeneration in Guild Wars 2. For example, the one from the guardian's [Virtue of Resolve](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Virtue_of_Resolve), or the Elementalist's [Soothing Mist](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Soothing_Mist).

Which one brings the most health per second (at equivalent healing power stat)?

Comment: Note, the scope of this question includes also regeneration from some items, like banners

Comment: It's also worth noting that passive regeneration is not the same as the boon 'Regeneration'. Another which grants passive regen is [Signet of the Wild](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Signet_of_the_Wild)

Comment: @DavidYell - I mean it in the wide sense. If there is a skill/trait granting the "regeneration" boon for a while, and that is more effective than other passives, it would be interesting as answer as well.

Comment: The regeneration boon will always outstrip any passive regeneration. Meaning there are kinda two answers to this question. As your title is passive, it doesn't really cover the regeneration boon.

Comment: Having done the math, I've proved myself wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### List criteria

Here is a list of all the passive regeneration skills and traits that I can find on the wiki. The criteria for this list is that the health must be regenerated by simply having the skill or trait, without an active effect or condition. This is why traits such as the Theifs [Shadow's Rejuvenation](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Shadow%27s_Rejuvenation) did not make this list.

### Skills and Traits

**Warrior**, [Healing Signet](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Healing_Signet), [Adrenal Health](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Adrenal_Health)
**Guardian**, [Virtue of Resolve](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Virtue_of_Resolve)
**Ranger**, [Signet of the Wild](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Signet_of_the_Wild)
**Engineer**, None?
**Thief**, None?
**Necromancer**, None?
**Elementalist**, [Soothing Mist](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Soothing_Mist)
**Mesmer**, None?

### So which is best?

Let's take a Healing Power of 100 and a time of 3 seconds.

Healing Signet,
`At level 80: 200 + (Healing Power * 0.033) per second`
= 609.9hp

Adrenal Health,
`1 Bar of Adrenaline - 125 health every 3s

2 Bar of Adrenaline - 240 health every 3s

3 Bar of Adrenaline - 360 health every 3s`
= Answers in the question ;)

Virtue of Resolve,
`0.06 * Healing Power + 84 per second`
= 270hp

Signet of the Wild,
`62+6% of Healing Power, per second`
= 204hp

Soothing Mist,
`Level + 0.05 * Healing Power per second`
= 255hp

### How does this compare to Regeneration?

Regneration boon
`130 + (0.125 * Healing Power) per second`
= 427.5hp

### Conclusion

The Warriors Healing Signet gives the best passive regeneration.

Comment: Not too sure on the math for the Warriors Healing Signet from the wiki. Although it can out-regen bleeding.

Comment: Thanks for doing the research (and the math)! Although I think that those rankings change a bit for the higher values of healing power (I think the max possible is 1335). Past around 760 of healing power, Regeneration becomes more effective than Healing signet. However, this is the only difference.

Comment: It's surprising to see that the class which is actually the best at supporting via health regeneration is the warrior. With banners and the trait which gives regeneration boon to allies in their range, it's the strongest passive regeneration. Of course, that remains for the passive regen only. As far as group support goes, the guardian is probably better equipped with protection, aegis, and zone heals.